# ASP.NET MVC Windows or Forms authentication based on IP address of the machine/ access location

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I need to authenticate users for my web application **based on where they are accessing the website from.** 
If the user is accessing the website from within the web server(locally), then it should ask for forms authentication(prompt for user id and pwd), since any user who is **not in AD also must be able to access**. 
It is **not anonymous** since **non AD users** need to enter the userid and password provided to them by their manager/admin.
 Some users might be temp users who are not in AD, hence forms authentication in this case where they are accessing the website on the server locally.
If the user is accessing the website (using static IP of the web server or the server where the website is hosted), by browsing to that URL **from his/her desktop(remotely),** then it should take **windows authentication**
automatically and not prompt the user for the UID and Pwd
I am using asp.net mvc 4 code first approach. Appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks
T